# numpy string file row to float array scientific notation

Tags: string, file, numpy, matrix-multiplication, scientific-notation

I have csv files with a 4x4 matrix ennumerated in each row and more than 300 rows in each file. 
I would like to numpy.multiply each 4x4 matrix by a [0,0,0,1]
I have tried converting with numpy.array, numpy.matrix, etc, and also tried to change the original notation with no avail.
the format of the rows I want to process:

```
camera1="[['9.5820988666217111e-001','1.8364288924172481e-002','2.8547603401192861e-001','-1.0076250938522580e+001'],['-1.7086800960614995e-001','-7.6361969781499617e-001','6.2264683441110236e-001','-4.5906868751556480e+001'],['2.2942958919045936e-001','-6.4540507435349748e-001','-7.2857007460000278e-001','2.1664174288937179e+001'],['0.0000000000000000e+000','0.0000000000000000e+000','0.0000000000000000e+000','1.0000000000000000e+000']]"
```

I am a bit confused as for what is the difference between matrix and array in terms of numpy and which I should use. What I would like to achieve for every row is the product

```
9.58209887e-01  1.83642889e-02  2.85476034e-01  -1.00762509e+01
-1.70868010e-01 -7.63619698e-01 6.22646834e-01  -4.59068688e+01
2.29429589e-01  -6.45405074e-01 -7.28570075e-01 2.16641743e+01
0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00
```

multiplied by

```
0,0,0,1,
```

to obtain

```
[[0.0,0.0,0.0,-10.07625094],
[ -0.0,-0.0,0.0,-45.90686875],
[0.0,-0.0,-0.0,21.66417429],
[0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0]]
```

but I only get errors like Not Implemented and so.
Any clue?

This would be my python script:

```
import numpy as nm

def getCoord(fila):
#lee la línea y extrae las coordenadas XYZ
    vect=fila.split('=')
    print (vect)
    camID=vect[0]
    trMatrix=vect[1]
    b=[0,0,0,1]
    crs=nm.multiply(trMatrix,b)[0:3]
    return camid,crs

unFichero=r"docmatrix.txt"
with open('outfile.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write(r"camera,coorx,coory,coorz")
    with open(unFichero) as infile:
        transf=getCoord(infile.read())
        f.write(transf[0]+","+transf[1]+'\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to convert the string to a list and then to an array, which seems to do the trick:

```
import numpy as np
import ast
string="[['9.5820988666217111e-001','1.8364288924172481e-002','2.8547603401192861e-001','-1.0076250938522580e+001'],['-1.7086800960614995e-001','-7.6361969781499617e-001','6.2264683441110236e-001','-4.5906868751556480e+001'],['2.2942958919045936e-001','-6.4540507435349748e-001','-7.2857007460000278e-001','2.1664174288937179e+001'],['0.0000000000000000e+000','0.0000000000000000e+000','0.0000000000000000e+000','1.0000000000000000e+000']]"
c=ast.literal_eval(string)
```

and then

```
cc=np.array(c).astype(float)
```

This way I now have an array of floats
And now I can define

```
d=[0,0,0,1]
prod=np.multiply(cc,d)
```

obtaining

```
>>> prod
array([[  0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        , -10.07625094],
       [ -0.        ,  -0.        ,   0.        , -45.90686875],
       [  0.        ,  -0.        ,  -0.        ,  21.66417429],
       [  0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   1.        ]])
```

What I wanted was to get XYZ coordinates from this 4x4 matrix

```
coor=[prod[0,3],prod[1,3],prod[2,3]]
```

Now I have

```
>>> coor
[-10.07625093852258, -45.90686875155648, 21.664174288937179]
```

So, any way, just for the records, I am posting this solution. Perhaps somebody can show me a better way.
Thank you, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

here's the final script:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import numpy as np
import ast

def getCoord(fila):
#lee la línea y extrae las coordenadas XYZ
    vect=fila.split('=')
    camID=vect[0]
    print vect[1]
    trList=ast.literal_eval(vect[1])
    trArray=np.array(trList).astype(float)
    print trArray
    b=[0,0,0,1]
    prod=np.multiply(trArray,b)
    coor=[prod[0,3],prod[1,3],prod[2,3]]
    return camID,prod[0,3],prod[1,3],prod[2,3]

unFichero=r"c:\temp\docmatrix.txt"
with open('outfile.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write("camera,coorx,coory,coorz\n")
    with open(unFichero) as infile:
        for row in infile.readlines():
            transf=getCoord(row)
            print transf
            f.write(','.join(str(e) for e in transf)+'\n')
```